# Java how to operate on BigDecimal values

Tags: java, algorithm, bigdecimal

Given the following conditions:

- two BigDecimal values: **b1** and **b2**;
- **x** - Integer;
- **b1 > b2**;

I need to find

the minimum value of **x** such that

**b2 * x > b1**

For example, if all values - Integer, than:

```
 if ( b1%b2 == 0 ) {
   x = b1/b2;
 } else {
   x = b1/b2 +1; 
 }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: `BigDecimal` supports all basic arithmetic operations; see e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html.  I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure you need BigDecimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
BigInteger x = b1.divide(b2, 0, RoundingMode.CEILING).toBigInteger()
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [API for the BigDecimal class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). You will find methods with names like [`add(BigDecimal)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add%28java.math.BigDecimal%29), one for each elementary operator. Use these methods.

e.g.:

```
if(b1.divide(b2).equals(BigDecimal.ZERO))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    BigDecimal bd1= .....;
    BigDecimal bd2= .....;

    BigDecimal tmp = bd2;
    int x = 0;
    while(tmp.compareTo(bd1) < 1){
        x++;
        tmp = bd2.multiply(new BigDecimal(x));
    }
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!! " + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
        BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(41);
        BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(10);
        BigDecimal xBigDec;
        BigInteger xBig;
        int x;
        if(BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(b2)){
            if(BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(b2)>0){
               x = 0;
            }else{
              //Can't do!
            }
        }else{
            xBigDec = b1.divide(b2);
            xBig = (xBigDec).toBigInteger();
            //you need to expand for negatives here
            if(xBig.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE))>0){
                x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }else{
                x = xBig.intValue();
                if(b2.multiply(new BigDecimal(x)).equals(b1)){
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason `x` can't be a `BigInteger` or `long`? What if `x < Integer.MIN_VALUE`?